# Math.random() not working properly when using return

Tags: java, math, random

I have a program in which I want an object to return a value between two numbers. But the problem is that most of the time, the numbers I get are not in the boundaries. Here's the code:

```
public int getSize() {
  int s = (int)Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  return s;
}
```

min and max are both defined in the code as 320 and 640, but i sometimes get values which are lower than what I need (for example I once got 283), and sometimes higher. Could anyone help please?

Comment: I doubt you get values lower than min if max>min. Your problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: BTW: it's usually better to use a preinstantiated java.util.Random object.

Comment: I actually didn't about java.util.Rabdom, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see how you could possibly get `283` if `min`/`max` are `320`/`640`.

That said, there is a bug in your code that would make it always return `min`. To fix it, use the following:

```
int s = (int)(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
```

Note the added parentheses. Without them, you're casting the result of `Math.random()` to `int`. This always gives zero, making the entire expression evaluate to `min`.

Comment: It may actually be me misusing the command, but I'm pretty sure I once got 283. And i had parenthesis in my code. But hanks a lot :)

Comment: @icecubelux: Are you saying that the code you show isn't the exact code that's giving you the problem?

Comment: I forgot the parenthesis, but that's all

Answer (score 2):

if you have access to C#, can you try the following? This is functionally equivalent to your task and should not generate numbers outside of 320 and 640 range. If this is so, you can compare logic of your Java code with it to see where you make a mistake.

```
namespace TestRand
{
    class TestRand
    {
        private static Random r;

        private const int min = 320;
        private const int max = 640;

        public static void Main()
        {
            r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", i, getSize());
            }
        }

        public static int getSize()
        {  
            int s = (int)(r.NextDouble() * (max - min)) + min;
            return s;
        }
    } 
}
```